# <Space> doesn't insert a space within a function

Tags: functions, whitespace

So I'm trying to have a function type out a space which goes as follows:

```
function! UnderlineHeading(level)
  if a:level == 1
    normal! yypVr=
  elseif a:level == 2
    normal! yypVr-
  else
    normal! I###<Space><Esc>
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>u3 :call UnderlineHeading(3)<cr>
```

However, when I press `<leader>u3` in normal mode, the function enters `<Space>` instead of an actual space. I have tried making the word `space` all lowercase (in vain). What causes this to happen and how should I go about fixing it?

If can be of any importance for this question, I use neovim.

Comment: Of interest: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/c732b74287d50d229de3c93dd1d9e05e442121ea/links/vim/autoload/bk/markdown.vim#L39 and https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/c732b74287d50d229de3c93dd1d9e05e442121ea/links/vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that commands such as `:normal!` don't really recognize and expand key sequences such as `<Space>` or even `<Esc>`.

Simply adding an actual *space* character would do the job here (`normal! I###` ), but this means you would have a trailing space in your command-line.

(Note that you don't really need an actual `<Esc>` character to leave insert mode from a `:normal!` command, since it will always end Insert mode implicitly at the end of its execution.)

The alternative to that is to use `:execute`, which allows you to assemble the `:normal!` command from a string, in which case you can use:

```
execute 'normal! I### '
```

That way the space is very clear.

Using `:execute` also allows you to use a double quoted string, where you can use key codes such as `<Esc>` as long as you use a backslash escaped `<` to initiate it. An example:

```
execute "normal! I### \<Esc>"
```

(Or, equivalently, `execute "normal! I### \e"`, since `\e` is also a valid escape for the `<Esc>` character. But then, again, you don't really need an explicit `<Esc>` in a `:normal!` command.)

Comment: Nice timing! :P

Comment: @D.BenKnoble When that happens, I'm always glad when our answers are in agreement. :-) Also I hadn't caught that `###` was part of what was being inserted, so glad to see that in your answer and correct mine.

Answer (score 2):

`:normal` doesn't (?) interpret `<>` sequences. You could use

```
normal! I###
```

But the hidden space turns me off; I prefer

```
execute 'normal! I### '
```

in this case because it makes the spacing apparent.